# Showing the parent site's welcome page as subsite's welcome page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation

is it possible to set the welcome page of subsites(child sites) to the welcome page of the root site. so as the users go to the subsites, they will see the default(welcome) page of the root site.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to redirect the users to the root site making the subsite rather useless, or show the same information on welcome page of the subsites as on the rootsite?

Comment: actually i have 5 level site-subsite hierarchy. in some levels sites are created only for purpose of creating hierarchy, they will not have real content. this is why i'm trying to do this.